# Counting Git Objects that are pushed and the way git counts pushed Objects

Tags: git, github, push

Is there a way to count and see the objects that were pushed to a repo?

I have been fiddling with GitHub for a few days and was able to reach to a point where I do a git init, git add, git commit, then git remote add and git push.

Thing is, If I need to know exactly which objects git pushed, how do I find that?

Initially I had a Readme.txt file and was able to push it to GitHub.

```
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$ git push origin master 
Username for 'https://github.com': my.email@address.com 
Password for 'https://my.email@address.com@github.com': 
Counting objects: 3, done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 276 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. 
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) 
To https://github.com/ugrankar/mydotfiles.git 
 * [new branch]      master -> master 
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$
```

I understand that Git refers to the directories and files with a 40 char hex checksum and really doesn't care about the file names.

So when it says 3 objects, it's actually counting *and* pushing the following 3 objects:
1) The Git Commit Object
2) The Object that corresponds to the Readme.txt file.
3) The Working Tree Object (Which in this case is the mydotfiles directory).

I could confirm that by using the git rev-list --objects --all command followed by git show checkum command.

I also understand that the moment I run git init, a .git directory is placed into the "mydotfiles" directory, converting it into what Git calls as a Working Tree which has a Git Repository (.git directory) associated with it.

Now I copied the Readme.txt file and named the copy as Oncemore.txt, then added, commited and pushed it. This time, Git still says it's counting 3 objects (But pushing two):

```
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$ git push origin master 
Username for 'https://github.com': my.email@address.com 
Password for 'https://my.email@address.com@github.com': 
Counting objects: 3, done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 254 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. 
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

But I thought it should be counting five objects, because, Git being a content address system, it should know that the content of Readme.txt and Oncemore.txt is the same. So it should be the three objects as mentioned above plus the following two:

4) The Commit Object for the Oncemore.txt file 
5) The new Working Tree Object that was generated after committing the Oncemore.txt file

It even confirms that. I ran the following command just before pushing:

```
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$ git ls-files --stage 
100644 b70f72952f495b2aae83f2ff1a50b5ee8d001edb 0   Oncemore.txt 
100644 b70f72952f495b2aae83f2ff1a50b5ee8d001edb 0   Readme.txt
```

Just to be sure, I did the following:

```
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$ git ls-files --stage | awk {'print $2'} | sort | uniq 
b70f72952f495b2aae83f2ff1a50b5ee8d001edb 
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$
```

And, the revlist command confirms that there are indeed five objects in there:

```
[pmu@t430 mydotfiles]$ git rev-list --objects --all 
95a4dadd90f0ba7b7f8f8a63700c8431bbbd1502 
77e873b76261df2a81eeb4738d2c6973e52f96b7 
611617fde6aafb5b6052f82e6a9608a015a9f88b 
b70f72952f495b2aae83f2ff1a50b5ee8d001edb Oncemore.txt 
82b77782f1229558a493b74b7faebad84d38e9ae
```

What I want to know is how can I "see" the objects that git pushed right after I run the git push origin master ? Is there a way exactly see what it pushed? Why is it counting 3 objects and pushing two? Is it that it needs to count the objects so that it can determine what's changed and then decide what needs to be pushed? In that case, shouldn't it count 5 objects (instead of 3) and push only two?

Where am I getting this wrong? Or am I just being ignorant and stupid? :)

Comment: Each git commit is just the snapshot of currently git repository. We can say that it has nothing to do with previous status, though git won't create objects that are already there, i.e. no new blob object for `Oncemore.txt`. And it neither needs to push the existing objects. I think that's why it counts 3 (blob object for `Oncemore.tx`, tree object and commit object) but push 2 (tree object and commit object).

Comment: Hi Landys, thanks for the reply. I just wish there was a confirmed way to see which objects are pushed.